# Compare two columns using Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I don't have much experience using google sheets and I'm having trouble with comparing two columns.

Sheet 1 has a this data in column A

```
Sheet 1 Column A
Tim
Pete
Chris
George
Sam
```

Sheet 2 has this in column B

```
sheet 2 Column B
Chris
George
```

How can I compare the two and output the names that don't appear in sheet 2 column B?

Thanks.

Comment: `=FILTER` with `COUNTIF`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a two step process, I've explained it as much as I could so you can modify the formulae if needed:

**1**. Use a Vlookup to identify the names that are in Sheet 1 Column A but NOT in Sheet2 column B.
In my example I did this using this formula in Sheet 1 Column B:

> =IFERROR(ARRAYFORMULA( IF(A1:A="","",VLOOKUP(A1:A,Sheet2!$B$1:$B,1,false))),"not found")

This formula simply compares Column A(Sheet 1) with Column B(Sheet 2) and marks the ones that are not there with "not found".
[Here's an Image to help you out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Goml2.png)

**2**. Use a filter to output all the names from Sheet 1 column A that are NOT in Sheet 2 column B. This is now possible since you previously identified them through our first formula.

> =FILTER(A1:A,B1:B="not found")

This will output all candidates in column B(Sheet 1) that were marked as "not found". I placed this in Column C(Sheet 1). Basically this column will output what you want.

[Here's another image to help you out with Step 2.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hPi8s.png)

You can keep adding names in Column A(Sheet 1) and comparing them with names in Column B(Sheet 2) and it will always show them in Column C(Sheet 1) since I included an arrayformula in Step 1.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks! Was very helpful :)